# POST oauth token sends initially OPTIONS request without data / headers and fails with 401

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

i have a problem with fetching oauth token from spring boot backend from react axios using :

```
async login() {
const tokenurl = 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token';
const data = {
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password,
  scope: 'write'
};
var headers = {
  headers: {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa('client:secret') ,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}
axios.post(tokenurl,data,headers)
```

a first OPTION request without headers / data is sent and 401 fails.

```
Access is denied (user is anonymous)
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied.
```

This is the request i received in my backend, the header / data are removed.

```
[OPTIONS /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Referer: http://localhost:3000/signin/
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

Option request / post token are working successfully in curl as well as in Postman with get new access token.

```
curl -X POST -u "client:secret" -d "grant_type=password&username=tata@tata.com&password=test&scope=write" -H "origin:http://localhost:3000" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

curl -X OPTIONS -u "client:secret" -d "grant_type=password&username=tata@tata.com&password=test&scope=write" -H "origin:http://localhost:3000" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

I noticed with removing -u "client:secret" in the curl OPTIONS request leads to the the same error as axios.

Spring Boot Backend security and oauth2.0 configuration :

WebSecurityConfig :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().httpBasic().realmName(securityRealm).and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean(name="CorsSource")
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();    configuration.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
    }
}
```

RessourceConfig :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/**").hasRole("PROVIDER").antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("CLIENT").antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
configurer.inMemory().withClient(clientId).secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret)).authorizedGrantTypes(grantType).scopes(scopeRead,scopeWrite).resourceIds(esourceIds); //ressourceIds:api,admin
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how can i fix this problem ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of searching i could find a workaround to fix my problem in spring boot backend, in fact with enabling the authorizationServer, the framework will configure the permissions to access the oauth endpoints in the class AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration and doesn't whitelist the OPTION method, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/330

to fix the 401 problem : 
1. in spring security config i added :

```
// ignore spring security preflight request for oauth (OPTIONS)
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/**");
}
```

and i added a cors filter, which will return OK by default if the method is OPTIONS.
 (to avoid any conflict, i removed the use of the CorsConfigurationSource and the http.cors() in the ScurityConfig, see implementation in my question). The filter is ordered as HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE and it should be the first executed for each request.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@WebFilter("/*")
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    public CorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }
}
```

this workaround fixes my problem, but it's not a perfect solution, i will be very happy to get some other solutions.